# Querying output media devices (with labels) impossible on a machine with no input media devices?

Tags: javascript, audio

I need to list the available *audio output* options on the user's machine. For this, the [MediaDevices.enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) method can be used, which returns a Promise of an array of MediaDeviceInfo elements:

```
let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
```

Now I need to display a selection dropdown list for the user. This dropdown is supposed to be populated with the name of each device, which is available through the `MediaDeviceInfo.label` property, but only if the user gave permission to access audio devices in response to a `MediaDevices.getUserMedia` call (otherwise the `label` property is an empty string).

So, with that in mind, this is how one is supposed to do it:

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

devices.forEach(deviceInfo => console.log(deviceInfo.label));
```

Now there's a little problem here...

`MediaDevices.getUserMedia` requires either one audio *input*, or video *input* to be present on the users machine, and will instantly throw if there is none! That is, I cannot use it to query *output* devices on the user's machine, if that machine has no *input* devices, which is quite hilarious, to say the least.

**So how am I supposed to query output devices on a machine with no input devices?**

---

*Note: this is in latest Chrome, and the question is related to JavaScript on the web, i.e. not Electron and the like, which do not display this problem.*

Comment: It is a little bit hard to reproduce, need to simulate a situation without input devices. Sounds like a Chrome bug, perhaps file a bug report there?
Which exception is being thrown?

Comment: @Tommos -- It is a `DevicesNotFoundError`, which is the Chrome-specific error for `NotFoundError` ([specs](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia)). From what I understand, it is _supposed_ to throw in this case, as there is indeed no audio input device. The problem is, this also prevents output devices from being queried with labels.

Comment: Yes I see. I guess the API design is just not quite done, linking audio input permissions to output is questionable, but the fact that it just breaks without input devices is not good at all. It sucks but I guess you'll have to find a workaround. Since you can detect this exception, it's probably best to write a manual on how to change the OS's default output for instance for these users?